# Why does the leveldb DB::Get API use std::string as value type?

Tags: binary, leveldb

I wanna to store key(url) & value(jpg image) in leveldb. As it is said,

> Keys and values are arbitrary byte arrays.

how can I use the DB::Get API?

Answer (score 3):

Slice does not own the memory (just points to it), so returning a Slice would mean that the caller should free the memory.

So a type with value semantics is needed.

The natural value for binary array would be `std::vector<uint8_t>`, as it implies so. But `std::string` can also be used instead (as you pointed out in your answer), and it is more useful if you expect to read a real string (no casting needed).

The main problem is that the reason is not documented, though.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it! c++ std::string use size() method to get the data length, use .data() get the data value. c++ std::string is not terminated by '\0', but specified by the size() function!

Comment: Actually the underlying data _is_ guaranteed to be terminated by a `'\0'` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you use an iterator, you can pull the data directly from the `iter->Value()` function which returns a slice. This avoids copying into the intermediate string.